# mouse keeps reconnecting & moves automatically

Tags: motherboard, mouse, connection

I bought a mouse two months ago but it is constantly disconnecting and reconnecting, sometimes moving the cursor without user input. I thought it might be an issue with the mouse itself, but I tested it with another computer and the mouse works just fine.

I have tried all common solutions on forums. One of my friends said there might be a problem with my motherboard, but I don't know how to troubleshoot for that. Could anyone confirm that this might be the cause of the problem?

1.mouse is wired from redgear local brand
2. i tried updating driver
3. people recommend to turn off power management option from USB root hub properties from device manager
4. tried switching ports

Comment: What brand of mouse? Wired or wireless? What are the common solutions you tried? Operating system? Please edit with this information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is in Device Manager. Check your mice and other pointing devices if it is updated, if not then update it. And if it is external mouse maybe the wires have defect in it. And if it still moves on its own, there may be a ghost  if your house. Hahaha.

Comment: yes drivers are updated thats the first thing i checked. i used mouse with my laptop workd fine